# How to connect to AWS IoT MQTT broker without certificates in a NestJS application also keep security in mind?

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

After successfully creating an AWS IoT Thing using the AWS SDK, I'm now seeking guidance on how to establish a secure MQTT connection for both publication and subscription. While I understand the conventional method of securing the connection through certificates, my challenge lies in implementing this without certificates. This is because the AWS SDK's Thing creation process does not automatically provide certificates. Could someone offer insights or best practices on how to securely connect to MQTT without certificates in such a scenario?

I'm looking to securely manage all my AWS IoT Things using a single MQTT connection in a NestJS application. How can I achieve this without relying on certificates?